# How to avoid function repetition in SELECT, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dry

I am writing a statistical query where the value is duplicated in `SELECT`, `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY`. Having to repeat the same value makes it hard to read the query and modify it.

How can I avoid repeating `FLOOR(COALESCE(LEN(Body), 0) / 100)` 3-4 times in the query below.

```sql
SELECT FLOOR(COALESCE(LEN(Body), 0) / 100) * 100 as BodyLengthStart,
    (FLOOR(COALESCE(LEN(Body), 0) / 100) + 1) * 100 - 1 as BodyLengthEnd,
    COUNT(*) as MessageCount
FROM [Message]
GROUP BY FLOOR(COALESCE(LEN(Body), 0) / 100)
ORDER BY FLOOR(COALESCE(LEN(Body), 0) / 100)
```

The output of the query is the number of messages bucketed by how many hundreds of characters they have.

| BodyLengthStart | BodyLengthEnd | MessageCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 99 | 130 |
| 100 | 199 | 76 |
| 200 | 299 | 36 |

Comment: Please provide few sample data and expected output if possible.

Comment: cross apply....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option may be a CTE (Common Table Expression), something along these lines:

```
WITH x AS
(
    SELECT FLOOR(COALESCE(LEN(Body), 0) / 100) AS BodyLength
    FROM [Message]
)
SELECT BodyLength * 100 AS BodyLengthStart,
       (BodyLength + 1) * 100 - 1 AS BodyLengthEnd,
       COUNT(*) as MessageCount
FROM x
GROUP BY BodyLength
ORDER BY BodyLength
```

As a side note - if the statement prior to this doesn't end with a semi-colon (;), this will not work as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Using CROSS APPLYs

```
SELECT  BodyLengthStart,
        BodyLengthEnd,
        COUNT(*)
FROM  [Message]
CROSS APPLY (
   VALUES 
      (FLOOR(COALESCE(LEN(Body), 0) / 100)) 
   ) a1(v)
CROSS APPLY (
   VALUES
      (v * 100, (v + 1) * 100 - 1)
   ) a2(BodyLengthStart, BodyLengthEnd)
GROUP BY BodyLengthStart,
         BodyLengthEnd
```

Comment: Is there a reason the transformations for the second cross apply aren't done in the `SELECT`?

Comment: @Redline, .. definetly it could be done in the `select`. Just wanted to show how the second `cross apply` uses the result of the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Use a sub-select:

```
SELECT  BodyLengthStart,
        BodyLengthEnd,
        COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT FLOOR(COALESCE(LEN(Body), 0) / 100) * 100 as BodyLengthStart,
            (FLOOR(COALESCE(LEN(Body), 0) / 100) + 1) * 100 - 1 as BodyLengthEnd
        FROM [Message]) as a
GROUP BY BodyLengthStart,
         BodyLengthEnd
```

You can define a `SELECT` after the `FROM`; in this way, you can elaborate previously your data.

Comment: Aka _derived table_.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common table expression:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
SELECT FLOOR(COALESCE(LEN(Body), 0) / 100) * 100 as BodyLengthStart,
    (FLOOR(COALESCE(LEN(Body), 0) / 100) + 1) * 100 - 1 as BodyLengthEnd
FROM [Message]
)
SELECT BodyLengthStart,BodyLengthEnd,COUNT(*)
FROM cte
GROUP BY BodyLengthStart,BodyLengthEnd
```